# Performnace related issue in loop through list and document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, generics

May be this is a silly programming question.

am performing a CAML QUERY which fetches some 500+ records, a  `projectcode` column from a splist and am inserting into a `list<string>` object. 
This is performed inside a timer job, within the `Execute()` .

Now I need to traverse to a  `document library` with this `projectcode` column and need fetch  those records that matches same `projectcode`. Both these list and doc lib are in the same site collection.

Wanted to know which feature of C# will i use ? I am having array, list<> , hashtable or something new.
**Which one is more performant ?**

Some CAML QUERY that fetches the projectcode from the splistitecollection object

`list<String> objProjCodes = new List<string>();`

and in the foraech loop, am adding the

```
if (currlistem["projeccode"] != null)
{
 objProjCodes.add(currlistitem["projectcode"].tostring());
}
```

Is there any way, I can perform this operation in a more high performant way?
other than list<> or array, any other new collection class, can be used here? so that,performance will b li'l bit better!

Now I need to traverse to a document library that's having same projectcode 
and fetch all those listitemcolletion , again by using different CAML query.
After this, I need to perform permission management on these selected items in the document library.

Cant use the itemevent receiver since I am having a comparison with datecolumn with todaysdate and this sourcelist is not getting updated by manually. Its a  scheduled job.

Kind of OLTP system, having primary key and foriegn key concepts. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Any performance issues you're having are more likely to be due to how you're accessing the sharepoint lists, rather than the costs of a hashtable vs generic list. Looping through all items in a library is going to be an inherently slow process (compared to accessing the same number of rows in a sql database).  But check out [request batching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798420.aspx). Also, perhaps check into the possibility of doing [joins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx) (just scroll down a bit on that page).

Another possibility (which perhaps is what you're already doing) would be to load all the data up-front, do the joins in memory, and then send batch updates back as needed, instead of repeatedly querying the list for matching records.

Other standard performance advice applies: make sure you're returning only the fields you need, instead of all fields in the list.

Of course, with timer jobs, the standard warning applies: MS is moving away from the server-side code model, and at some point you may want to consider a powershell script that uses the client side object model instead of chewing up server memory for this operation.